# SHA512-CRYPT MariaDB passwords migration to DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, mariadb, encryption, amazon-dynamodb

I used to run my mail server's DB in MariaDB (10.5.16) on-prem on Debian 10. I've now migrated this to RDS, however I would also like to try and migrate to DynamoDB.
Most of the data is plaintext, however per say in my account table I have my passwords as encrypted SHA512-CRYPT strings.

What should I do to properly and securely migrate this to DynamoDB?
I believe the encryption/decryption of the passwords used to happen on the local machine using openssl rather the database engine?
That being said if I am to simply migrate these encrypted SHA512 strings into DynamoDB attributes, they won't be translated to plaintext data when called, yes?

I'm pretty bad with DBA stuff and this is for my personal mail server.. Would appreciate any help for the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Try it.  That is, hope that DynomoDB and MariaDB and RDS all did the "right" thing, and you have to do nothing.  (There are more moving parts than you mentioned.)

Comment: Hi @RickJames you are right there's more moving pieces. I had a look into my dovecot setup and it seems I'm using the dovecot-mysql to interact with my database. Furthermore I also see the SHA512 strings are actually manually generated by me with the dovecot password utility, that being said the data can stay in DynamoDB in it's current encrypted form, however I have to figure out how to make Dovecot interact with my DynamoDB tables.

Comment: (I know nothing about those products.)  If necessary, a password check should test two ways -- once with the sha256, and once with the previous one-way hash.  Be sure that the password columns is a suitably long VARCHAR (if using hex) or BINARY (if packed).